# How to order characters

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have at column "A" an expression, like "EXP1" and on column "C" I need to make an order to be like this:

EXP1_1
EXP1_2
EXP1_3
etc.

Then again on column "A" I have EXP2, and column "C":

EXP2_1
EXP2_2
EXP2_3
etc.

[image: Here's the pic]

I don't know how to do this. I tried to order it automatically (Excel) but I couldn't figure how.

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried thusfar?

Comment: Can you please include a picture of what you're trying to do and what you tried so far ? It's impossible to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: https://www.contextures.com/xlSort01.html#videosortrow

Comment: Cyril, I tried to classifie from A to Z, but it says the area fixed together must be at the same size

Comment: Here's the picture: https://pasteboard.co/HAwBZ7q.jpg

Comment: You can upload the picture to your original question.

Comment: I edited that with the picture! Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If A1 contains `EXP1` then in C1 and copied down to suit:

```
=A$1&"_"&ROW()
```

might be what you want.

Since the only function is `ROW` unless say `0` for `O` my guess is that a `#NAME` error must be because a non-English version is in use, that requires ROW to be translated, maybe to `LIN`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! It worked fine bro!!! Really really thanks, I debt you this one... Thanks

Comment: From the picture I think every time there's a value in A, you want the counter to start over, so Row() or LIN() or whatever would keep growing, wouldn't it? I was thinking of like

 `+IF(A2<>"",A2&"_"&1,LEFT(B1,FIND("_",B1))&RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND("_",B1))+1)`

Starting in B2. I don't know if IF, LEFT, RIGHT, LEN, and FIND need to be translated.